# VSTS Hub events

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-rest-api

I have [added a new hub](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-hub) to TFS 2017 (on-premise) under the Build & Release tab. Can a hub attach/subscribe to events similar to the Build Summary for a particular build definition and the Release Summary for a particular release definition such as when builds/releases are queued/completed?

I have looked through the vss-web-extension-sdk and the "VSS/Events/Service" appear to only attach to PageEvents.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t attach/subscribe to the build or release in a general hub extension. You can do it in build/release summary extension.

There are samples of VSTS extension: [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)